# Angular syncfusion - What's the event for getting line chart selected series?

Tags: angular, angular7, series, linechart, syncfusion

I'm working with Line chart control from Syncfusion on Angular 7. I was going through the documentation, but couldn't find an event for getting selected data series when clicking on a line chart series. Would you be able to let me know what's the event name ?

The only thing i have found is chartMouseClick, but this one has only x and y point selected.

`chartMouseClick(args: IMouseEventArgs): void`

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would like to let you know that while clicking on particular point we can get both the selected data series and point values and its respective index. Hence we suggest you to use “pointclick” event to achieve your requirement. Based on that we have prepared a sample in EJ2 for your reference.

Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hnrhtv-9bwwdm?file=app.component.html

Code Snippet:
app.component.html:

```
<ejs-chart align='center' id='chartcontainer' [title]='title' [primaryXAxis]='primaryXAxis' (pointClick)="PointClick($event)">
```

app.component.ts:

```
public PointClick = function(args: IPointEventArgs): void { 
alert('SelectedSeriesIndex :' + args.seriesIndex); };
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Regarding this I also have one issue. Is it possible to find out when series is being deselected as well?